# How to clear more than one tkinter entry field using a function

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, callback, bind

I have a rather simple problem which is when I am in a particular tkinter entry field on my GUI when I press the backspace key it deletes the field of any text.
All was going well until I wanted to use this method on more than one entry field.

The code

```
import tkinter


class BuildWidgets:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master   # reference the main window
        self.BACKSPACE = ''

        self.TextBox = tkinter.Entry(self.master,width=10)
        self.TextBox.bind("<Key>", self.clearTextBox)
        self.TextBox.pack()

        self.TextBox2 = tkinter.Entry(self.master,width=10)
        self.TextBox2.bind("<Key>", self.clearTextBox2)
        self.TextBox2.pack()


    def clearTextBox(self,event):
        pressed = event.char
        if pressed == self.BACKSPACE:
            self.TextBox.delete(0,'end')

    def clearTextBox2(self,event):   #I want to eliminate repetitive methods
        pressed = event.char
        if pressed == self.BACKSPACE:
            self.TextBox2.delete(0,'end')
```

I basically bind the **key event** to the entry field and the callback checks if **backspace** was pressed and if so deletes the text. However,  when I add a second entry fields I need to create a second method and it goes on and on for each entry field! This is because I cannot find a way to pass the entry to field to a single method as it is a callback in a widget.

**Question**

How do I, or can I , create **a single clear** method that distinguishes which entry field is calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `event` object that is passed to the function has a `widget` attribute that is the widget that caught the error.

```
def clearTextBox(self,event):
    pressed = event.char
    if pressed == self.BACKSPACE:
        event.widget.delete(0,'end')
```

Comment: Hang on I will try it!

Comment: How did you find that out! I have looked in a number of sources and not come across this . great - thanks

Comment: Would you know how to pass an argument to a method that is a callback in a function by any chance - seeing as when you put the method name in the callback you don't put the brackets in

Comment: @TimothyLawman: there are many questions and answers on that subject here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @TimothyLawman: you clearly knew something called `event` was being passed in. Are you aware you can print `dir(event)` to see what attributes that object has?

Comment: Yes I realized event was an object being inherited but I hadn't the documentation, just found it on a uni web site and it lists all the methods available from the even object. Thanks